# Nearest statement - Mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, proximity, mapbasic

When I use the nearest statement in mapbasic, not all the "from table" points show up. For example I am looking for the nearest distance neighbor of every point in a table (called Points). I use this code:

```
Nearest From Table  Points to Points into result Ignore Min 0 units "km" Data Name =Points.Name  
Update result Set Distance =ObjectLen(obj, "km")
```

Not all "from table" points show up. Please see the example. No problem between B and C since they are close to each other. But as you see B shows up for the distance with A. This should not happen.

Can someone please help. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Isn't B being checked against A and vice versa? Do you have two output lines from the nearest statement between B and A?

Comment: Only one output between A and B which is correct but it should be for A not B since B already found its nearest neighbor C.

Comment: I think the output is correct. A has found B as the nearest point, therefore the name is populated with B. B found C and populated name with C, and C found B and populated name with B.

Comment: Thank @T_Bacon, makes sense.